# Sql group by max column value after CTE

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
WITH messages_ranked 
AS ( 
   SELECT p.Date, p.RecipientId, p.RecipientType, p.Id, p.text, p.userId,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.RecipientId, p.userId 
   ORDER BY p.Id DESC) 
   AS rk 

   FROM ChatMessages p
   JOIN ChatGroupMemberships as g 
   ON p.recipientId = g.groupId
   WHERE g.userId = XXX <-- user id
) 

SELECT date, recipientId as groupId, recipientType as groupType, id, text, userId, rk
FROM messages_ranked s 
where rk = 1

Order BY s.date DESC
```

Which yields me this:

[image: img1]

What I'd need is to reduce result rows of this query so that for every unique `groupId` only the row with highest value of `date` would be returned.

So for example from the first three rows only the first would be returned, as they share the same `groupId` and the first row has the newest date.

I tried to follow example here [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) as my question is closely related but I can't seem to do it right.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that this does what you want:

```
WITH messages_ranked AS ( 
      SELECT p.Date, p.RecipientId, p.RecipientType, p.Id, p.text, p.userId,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.RecipientId ORDER BY p.dATE DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM ChatMessages p JOIN
           ChatGroupMemberships as g 
           ON p.recipientId = g.groupId
      WHERE g.userId = XXX <-- user id
     ) 
SELECT date, recipientId as groupId, recipientType as groupType, id, text, 
       userId, seqnum
FROM messages_ranked s 
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY s.date DESC ;
```

I don't think you need to use `row_number()` twice.

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm and you really simplified it. This was a follow up for my previous question where I worked my way here. Accepting  in 10 minutes. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955002/sql-cte-scope-in-query